# How to make a comment on board in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am creating an application using Nodejs and React, but the comment function does not work. I do not know the cause.

Error :

> board validation failed: comments.0.content: Path `content` is required.

I don't know why this is not working. What mistake did I make?

route/api/board.js

```
router.post(
    '/:id/comments',
    [
        auth,
        [
            check('content', 'input your content. ')
                .not()
                .isEmpty()
        ]
    ],
    async (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() }, 'isEmpty');
        }

        try {
            const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
            const board = await Board.findById(req.params.id);
            const newComment = new Board({
                content: req.body.content,
                user: req.user.id
            });

            board.comments.unshift(newComment);

            await board.save();

            res.json(board.comments);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            res.status(500).send('Server error!!');
        }
    }
);
```

models/Board.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const BoardSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    view_count: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    likes: [
        {
            user: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'user'
            }
        }
    ],
    comments: [
        {
            user: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'user'
            },
            content: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            created_at: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            }
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = Board = mongoose.model('board', BoardSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty explicit, one of your comments in the `comments` array doesn't have a property `content` which seem to be required based on your model.

So double check what you are sending to the server by debugging/logging the content of the `req.body`.